# C Arithmetic Different Output

Tags: c

I'm getting different results when doing what I think is the same calculation.  I imagine it's a type conversion issue.

I'm pulling a temperature value from a `hardware sensor via I2C`.  The `datasheet` says the equation to do the conversion is as follows:

```
(((14_bit_ADC_value)/16382) * 165) - 40)
```

The two byte ADC value is stored in two chars and some shifting needs to occur to get the **14 bytes** as such:

```
((((rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2) / 16382) * 165) - 40);
```

The problem:

- If I break up the operations it works.
- If I combine them into one line it fails.

My Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char rawtemp[4];
  rawtemp[2] = 0x61; //example captured value
  rawtemp[3] = 0x40; //example captured value

  //method 1
  float test = 0;
  test = (rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2);
  test = test / 16382;
  test = test * 165;
  test = test - 40;
  printf("test1: %f C\r\n", test);  //This works.

  //method 2
  test = (((rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2) / 16382) * 165) - 40;
  printf("test2: %f C\r\n", test);  //This does not work.
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./k 
test1: 22.688316 C
test2: 1024280.000000 C
```

Why does the second method to derive the temperature value fail?

Comment: Just a hunch, someone else could probably give a better answer and prove it, but maybe division takes precedence over bitwise OR? Try adding parentheses. **EDIT**: See below comment(s).

Comment: `/` is an overloaded operator who's behaviour differs strongly depending on whether you have integer or floating point operands. Check that this isn't the problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt an "overloaded operator" in the **C** programming language! The word "overload" is not used anywhere in the index of K&R.

Comment: Both above are right. There are two(!) errors here.

Comment: Also `char` --> `unsigned char`

Comment: So what, @Jameson? Lending that word from C++ actually gives this thing a suitable name. You don't argue that it factually is overloaded, right? BTW: K&R is not a suitable reference, ISO is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the correct `method2` is :

```
 test = ((((rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2)) / 16382.0) * 165) - 40;
```

Comment: Holy crap, the answer is different if it's 16382 vs. 16382.0!

Comment: Not exactly the holy crap but the C language.

Comment: @Stateful slow down and think, do some research. Study the difference between integer and floating point division.

Comment: @david-herrernan Will do, I had no idea there was a difference. Going to do some reading to understand what's happening and why.

Comment: It's disappointing that this answer makes no attempt to explain anything

Answer (score 4):

There are two bugs in your method 2:

1. `(rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2) / 16382` should be `((rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2)) / 16382` , because the priority of bitwise OR is lower than divide.
2. In C, if the two operands of `'/'` are both int, the result is also int, or `floor(a/b)`, you can use `(float)((rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2)) / 16382` (or write 16382 as 16382.0) to convert one of the operand into float, then the result will also be int.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do the type cast of the expression `(rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2)`  to float as in

```
//method 2  
test = ((((float) ((rawtemp[2] << 6 ) | (rawtemp[3] >> 2))) / 16382) * 165) - 40;
```